# Equal distribution of data into groups

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with groups of people who have a number attached to their name. They are either a 1,2,3 or 4. I need to create groups where there is an even distribution of members in each group. In other words, I don't want all the 4's in one group, or all the 3's in another. I'd like it to be distributed evenly.
This is what I have so far. It echo's out the people and groups them by their level, but I'm not sure how to make groups of them that equally distributes their levels.
I have some more code and even though I've pissed off the community with my lack of experience, I was hoping someone might be able to tell me how to clean up the code. It works how I want it, but it feels ugly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

include_once 'connect.php';

$level1 = array();
$level2 = array();
$level3 = array();
$level4 = array();

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE level = 1";
$stmt = $handler->prepare($sql1);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach($row as $rows)
{

$level1[] = $rows['name'];

}

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE level = 2";
$stmt = $handler->prepare($sql2);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach($row as $rows)
{

$level2[] = $rows['name'];

}

$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE level = 3";
$stmt = $handler->prepare($sql3);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach($row as $rows)
{

$level3[] = $rows['name'];

}

$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE level = 4";
$stmt = $handler->prepare($sql4);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach($row as $rows)
{

$level4[] = $rows['name'];

}

$sql5 = "SELECT * FROM table";
$stmt = $handler->prepare($sql5);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
$result = count($row);

for($i=0; $i<=$result; $i++)
{

echo $level1[$i];
echo"<br>";
echo $level2[$i];
echo"<br>";
echo $level3[$i];
echo"<br>";
echo $level4[$i];
echo"<br>";

}

?>
```

Comment: @b0s3 *"I don't have any code as I'm in the "theoretical" phase right now."*

Comment: It dont need to be code. Atleast you can explain the least solution..

Comment: Stack Overflow is a place to get help with a problem with code you've written. Requests such as yours generally don't get much positive response. Start writing code to do this and when you run into a problem, post a question with the code that isn't working and someone will be glad to help you!

Comment: @Fred-ii- Meaningful. :)

Comment: @b0s3 Clearest question I've read in a while. Let me remove the mud from my glasses now ;-)

Comment: Ok...I'll write something out and then come back when I have something to post.

Comment: *"rather than just berate my lack of "stackoverflow" etiquette!!"* - Take it up with Stack or post on meta if you don't like the rules.

Comment: I apologize for my whining....it was early and the coffees were few!!!!

Comment: Questioner has added code since the question was first framed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a simple round-robin style of distribution, it requires a loop range of 1 to 4, uses that as an index to an array that accumulates counts for each group.  That may solve the problem you describe, if I have understood what you have asked.

If you are still in the theoretical side of this, draw a diagram of what you mean.  A code example would mean the answer could address your issue rather than address it theoretically.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to go to the proverbial drawing board and see if I can get the code up and running and then I'll post what I have. I appreciate your posting a possibility rather than just berate my lack of "stackoverflow" etiquette!!

Comment: It sounds like you have the idea in your head, but when you try and turn it into code, the uncertainty factor can mean what you code is not based on a real understanding of the issue.  I suggest a simple sequence diagram may help you to define it.  Your specification makes sense to me, you could post pseudo-code

Comment: I've figured out the code, but is there a way to put the 5 queries into 1?

Comment: Well done for adding the code, now this is starting to look like a question.  In mysql you can query based on a range.  You could do one query to get all the data, then output each level using a two dimensional array (where level is one array index).  Have a go, it is better to learn basic stuff by thinking about it.  The query would simply be your last query, then index your array by the level so you can then foreach each level.

Comment: thank you very much. I'll take a look at multidimensional arrays and see what I can find.

Comment: Use var_dump to examine the structure you get from fetchAll() - from the php.net manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php (check the return values section)